# array of structs in struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


typedef struct user {
    char *username;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
} user;

user* users;

typedef struct room
{
  char *roomname;
  user* users;
} room;

room* rooms;

int addToUsersArray(char *username) {
    int i = 0;

    for(; i<10; i++) {
            if(users[i].username=='\0') {
                    users[i].username = username;
                return 1;
            } else if(strcmp(users[i].username, username) == 0)
                return -1;
    }
    return -1;
}


void initUsersArray() {  
    users = (user*) calloc(10, sizeof(user)); 
}

void initRoomsArray() {  
rooms = (room*) calloc(10, sizeof(room));
    int i =0;   
    for(;i<10;i++)      
         rooms[i].users = (user*) calloc(10,sizeof(user));  
}

int addToRoomsArray(char *roomname) {
    int i = 0;

    for(; i<10; i++) {
            if(rooms[i].roomname=='\0') {
                    rooms[i].roomname = roomname;
                return 1;
            } else if(strcmp(rooms[i].roomname, roomname) == 0)
                return -1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int addUserToRoom(char *roomname, user usr) {
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for(; i<10; i++) {
            if(rooms[i].roomname=='\0') {
                    rooms[i].roomname = roomname;
                    return 1;
            } else if(strcmp(rooms[i].roomname, roomname) == 0) {
            for(;k<10;k++) {
                if(rooms[i].users[k].username==NULL) { //This line makes trouble
                    rooms[i].users[k] = usr;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return -1;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    initUsersArray();  
    initRoomsArray();      
    char *username = "Max";
    addToUsersArray(username);
    username = "Ma1x";
    addToUsersArray(username);
    printf("%s\n",users[0].username);
    printf("%s\n",users[1].username);

struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(4444);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");  

char *room = "sportchat";
addToRoomsArray(room);
room = "berlinchat";
addToRoomsArray(room);

    printf("%s\n",rooms[0].roomname);
    printf("%s\n",rooms[1].roomname);

user michi;
michi.username = "michi";
michi.addr = addr;

struct sockaddr_in addr2;
    addr2.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr2.sin_port = htons(1234);
    addr2.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.1.1");

user willi;
willi.username = "willi";
willi.addr = addr2;

addUserToRoom(room,michi);
addUserToRoom(room,willi);


    return 1;
}
```

When running addUserToRoom(room,michi) i get a segmentation fault. I am still a little bit unsure with using structs. When commenting out `rooms[i].users[k] = usr;` the segmentation fault disappears. I am using gcc on an unix system. Does gcc analyse an if-expression with an empty block?

**EDIT**
How do i implement a variable number of users and rooms? I think i have to use realloc. But how? 
Regards

Comment: C++ happens to be so much clearer in programs like these... You probably forgot to initialize some field. Too bad that you're using unix, Visual Studio would break you at the variable that's uninitialized.

Comment: first of all, avoid globals as much as you can ! in "if(rooms[i].users[k].username=='\0')" rooms[i].users is a null pointer, so missed some initialization somewhere, but your code is quite messy.

Comment: You should use `strcmp` class of function to compare *C strings* & not `==`

Comment: Do i may need to allocate mem for rooms[i].users? Should i compile with `-Wall -Wextra`. I am new to c and gcc.

Comment: `users[i].username=='\0'` does not what you probably think it does. `username` is a `char*` that is a pointer to a character array. You compare that pointer to the integer `'\0'`. By coincidence this integer is just the value `0` and so you actually test if `username` is set to something or not. But I guess that this is pure coincidence.

Comment: How about an intro to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never allocate memory, neither initialize

```
room.users
```

so when you try to access rooms[i].users[k] you get a segmentation fault.

as a side note: DON'T EVER USE GLOBALS, or you'll do stupid stuff (even more when you're using globals that have the same name as members of your structs). Also, always initialize your iteration variables in first part of for loops. (Do you know people died for less than that ? :P)

here is an example of what shall be your main function:

```
int main() {
    room* rooms;
    user* users;

    initUsersArray(users);
    initRoomsArray(rooms);

    char *username = "Max";
    addToUsersArray(users,username);
    username = "Ma1x";
    addToUsersArray(users,username);
    printf("%s\n",users[0].username);
    printf("%s\n",users[1].username);

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(4444);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    char *room = "sportchat";
    addToRoomsArray(rooms,room);

    /* ... */

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I am new to c. Why does using globals is so bad?

Comment: because you can not follow the life of each variable in your code. Usually, you declare your variable in your main() function, and then pass them to every function. see my next edit.

Comment: so that way, you have your rooms and users variables, and you can correctly follow their lifes, and have multiple instances of them. And you'll find out more easily where in your code you should have put the missing allocation/initialization of room.users

Comment: you can use realloc each time you add/remove a user from a room, but that will enforce a full copy of all the memory already allocated, and thus be a real performance drop. You shall better implement your room as a linked list of users, so you can easily remove or add users in your list : http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/c-linked-lists.html and as it really looks like a homework, I'm only giving you tips to make your code better, but I won't write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with that code. To answer the question, you haven't allocated the `rooms[i].users` array.